# WPF Save Settings

Tags: .net, vb.net, settings

Today I created an app where a user can create an image with background color and name chosen by him/her. But now I am facing this problem: when I try to save the settings(My.settings.bgcolor.save()) it saves the color but I am not able to see it in the
WPF Project>>Settings(it doesn't appear there and it doesn't appear in the settings.setting,but the application loads the new content).Any ideas?

Code as requested:

```
If (site.Text <> Nothing And num_tile.Text <> Nothing And cul <> Nothing) Then
        My.Settings.shortcuts_bgcolor.Add(cul)
        My.Settings.shortcuts_name.Add(num_tile.Text)
        My.Settings.shortcuts_website.Add(site.Text)
        Dim i As Integer = 0
        For Each shc As String In My.Settings.shortcuts_name
            MsgBox(My.Settings.shortcuts_name(i), MsgBoxStyle.Information)
            i += 1
        Next
        Dim window As MainWindow = New MainWindow
        window.IncarcaButoane()
        Me.Close()
    End If
End Sub

Private Sub Window_Closing(sender As System.Object, e As System.ComponentModel.CancelEventArgs) Handles MyBase.Closing
    My.Settings.Save()
End Sub

Private Sub Window_Closed(sender As System.Object, e As System.EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Closed
    My.Settings.Save()
End Sub
```

Comment: it would be a good idea to post some of the code that you feel is causing this problem. It would be difficult to guess what the actual problem is with just the description of the error.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The values you see in the project settings are just the defaults -- if the application applies changes, they don't get saved to that file.  For the actual location of the user settings, the first place I would look is under `%userprofile%\AppData\Local` or `%userprofile%\AppData\Roaming` (under your app's "Company Name" subfolder).  However, keep in mind that [the actual file location varies depending on the user's profile, and on the application type](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8eyb2ct1.aspx):

> The location of the app.exe.config and user.config files will differ based on how the application is installed. For a Windows Forms-based application copied onto the local computer, app.exe.config will reside in the same directory as the base directory of the application's main executable file, and user.config will reside in the location specified by the Application::LocalUserAppDataPath property. For an application installed by means of ClickOnce, both of these files will reside in the ClickOnce Data Directory underneath %InstallRoot%\Documents and Settings\username\Local Settings.
>
> The storage location of these files is slightly different if a user has enabled roaming profiles, which enables a user to define different Windows and application settings when he or she is using other computers within a domain. In that case, both ClickOnce applications and non-ClickOnce applications will have their app.exe.config and user.config files stored under %InstallRoot%\Documents and Settings\username\Application Data.

Comment: Well McGarnagle, Billy's DEAD

Comment: @Brad Hey! I'm *trying* to eat lunch here.